# koala and facebook how to get page id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I'm new on Facebook API and I'm experimenting them with Koala gem. I'm facing those situation right now:

- I have a canvas app, there is a way to retrieve the page id where the app has ben installed?
- On my canvas app can I fire an event when a user install the app? I'd like to know when someone install it and save page id and user id in my database.

Any hints are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this to install:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

At YOUR_URL,you can get the facebook parameter tabs_added.
Save it to database.